# Возможно ли получить удалённые данные?

Tags: java, mysql

Я делаю запрос.

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE field = ?;
```

Могу ли я получить результатом выполнения данного запроса данные, которые я им удалил?

Comment: Вы используете одну из тех редких БД, в которой это невозможно, в принципе.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сперва выбрать данные запросом SELECT, а потом удалить их. Чтобы не дать другим сессиям изменить данные между вашими SELECT и DELETE, можно сделать как-то так:

```
LOCK TABLES `table` WRITE;
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE field = ?;
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE field = ?;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Как вариант, вы можете реализовать свою систему так, чтобы она вообще не удаляла данные. "Удаленные" записи просто помечаете как удаленные (для этого таблице нужно еще одно поле). В запросы извлечения данных добавляете соответствующее условие - чтобы записи, помеченные как удаленные, не извлекались.

Comment: Да это и так понятно, просто думал возможно результатом удаления получить данные.